# Getting Key error while accessing json information

Tags: python, json

```
def modbus_message_decode(data_real):

    reg_address=(''.join(data_real[2:4]))
    print(reg_address)
    modbus_db_arg1= int(reg_address,16)
    print(modbus_db_arg1)
    modbus_db_arg2= (json_data['mb']['Simulator'][modbus_db_arg1])
```

Here, i am getting reg_address as 10001  (modbus_db_arg1)

it is throwing key error.

If i access without using variable like this, not getting error

```
modbus_db_arg2= (json_data['mb']['Simulator']['10001'])
```

please help me on this

thanks

Comment: `modbus_db_arg1` is an integer, while in the example without the error you use a string, which seems to be `reg_address`.

Comment: As Reti43 pointed out: `modbus_db_arg1= str(int(reg_address,16))`
should do the trick.

Comment: I have tried with this modbus_db_arg1= str(int(reg_address,16)). still it's not working

Comment: Why????? `int(reg_address, 16)` effectively produces `modbus_db_arg1`. Do you understand what you're trying to do?